# Oracle - Get data from past year (Dynamic)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have some question regarding about get data from database which need to fetch from past year ( dynamic , not hard-coded )

Table: BookingTable

```
bookingID   userID     Timebooked 
1             0003    10-May-2016
2             0001    10-May-2018
3             0001    10-Apr-2017
4             0001    10-Apr-2017
5             0003    10-Jan-2011
6             0006    10-Apr-2018
7             0003    10-Apr-2016
8             0006    10-Apr-2015
9             0001    10-Apr-2017
```

This is my code below

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(userID) AS count
FROM BookingTable 
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(userID) >2
```

Here is the result from my query above

```
userID  count
0001      4
0003      3
```

From the table i would like to add where the timebooked is from past year to current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sysdate - interval '1' year` to represent today's date one year ago:

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(userID) AS count
FROM BookingTable 
WHERE Timebooked BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' year AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(userID) > 2
```

As @Wernfried correctly pointed out below, the above would fail for February 29 in a leap year.  Instead, use this workaround:

```
WHERE Timebooked BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Hello Time, after adding "WHERE Timebooked >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' year" it will appear (NOT A GROUP BY expression)

Comment: Is `Timebooked` a date column?  What is the type?

Comment: DATE datatype with NOT NULL

Comment: Thank You for the help @Tim Biegeleisen , i just realized that I have some missing expression, everything is solved ! thanks for the help

Comment: `- INTERVAL '1' year` will fail on 29th of February. Consider to use `add_months(SYSDATE, -12)`

Comment: No, [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603) documentation says: *If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month.* `ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2016-02-29', -12)` returns `2015-02-28`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for this comment.  You clearly know Oracle very well.