# Joining Table Based on Result(After Query)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, conditional-statements

Previous Thread : [Oracle - Get data from past year (Dynamic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546830/oracle-get-data-from-past-year-dynamic)

Note: Need to join table to show a better result after the query(From previous thread) have been executed.

This is my userMember

userMember Table

```
userID   memberID 
0001     0001000
0003     0003000
0006     0006000
0008     0008000
0010     0010000
0013     0013000
```

my MembeTable

```
memberID  memberName
0001000      John
0003000      Doe
0006000      Rick
0008000      Jack
0010000      Cruise
0013000      Ronnie
```

I have some error when joining the table where it keeps on duplicate and I not able to obtain the memberName based on userID (From previous thread)

Expected Result(the result that I wanted)

```
userID  memberName  count
0001        John      3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you post the query that gave you duplicates?  We can work from there.

Comment: @kc2018 SELECT memberName,userID, COUNT(userID) AS count 
FROM BookingTable  b, userMember  u, MembeTable e
WHERE b.userID = u.userID
JOIN u.userID = e.userID
WHERE b.Timebooked  >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' year
HAVING COUNT(userID) >4
GROUP BY userID

Comment: @kc2018 can't run the query as show SQL wrong

Comment: MemberTable (e) does not have userID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.userID, m.memberName, COUNT(b.userID) AS count
FROM BookingTable b
INNER JOIN
userMember u
ON b.userID = u.userID
INNER JOIN
MembeTable m
ON u.memberID = m.memberID
WHERE b.Timebooked BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' year AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY b.userID, m.memberName
HAVING COUNT(b.userID) > 2;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cca97/1)

Comment: Thanks! everything works fine, and sorry for the delayed. I do have a question, hope that you can clear it out for me that is that possible "FROM BookingTable b, userMember u , MembeTable m"?

Comment: @whalesboy explicitly define the type of join (inner, left, right, etc) and the joint key is the standard way.  However, you could use `FROM BookingTable b, userMember u, MembeTable m WHERE b.userID = u.userID and b.memberID = m.memberID and b.Timebooked BETWEEN...`

Comment: @whalesboy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause-mysql - applies to SQL in general.